# GROUP BY an JSON field and pick first record of each group postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, postgresql

Trying to write a SQL:

**Table association:**

1. `A` has_many `B`s
2. `A` has a column `aa`
3. `B` has a `json` column `bb` like:

   `[{"d":"ddd", "e":"eee"}, {"d":"dqdq", "e":"eqeq"}]`

**My query would be like:**

Find all `A`s where (GROUP BY `bb->'d'` and pick first one) and order by `aa`

**Solution in Ruby:**

```
A.joins(:B).group_by do |b|
  b.bb.group_by { |bbb| bbb['d'] }.first
end.map { |_key, value| value.sort_by(&:aa).first }
```

**UPDATED**

**Tables:**

```
A
--------------
id  | aa
--------------
1   | 3.4
2   | 4.5
3   | 5.5
--------------

B
--------------
id | A_id | bb
--------------
1  | 2    | [{"d":"ddd", "e":"eee"}, {"d":"dqdq", "e":"eqeq"}]
2  | 1    | [{"d":"fff", "e":"ggg"}, {"d":"hhh", "e":"iii"}]
3  | 3    | [{"d":"ddd", "e":"jjj"}, {"d":"kkk", "e":"lll"}]
--------------

**After GROUP BY:**

"ddd" => [{A_id: 2, A.aa: 4.5}, {A_id: 3, A.aa: 5.5}],
"fff" => [{A_id: 1, A.aa: 3,4}]

Desired Outcome:
A
--------
id  | aa
--------
2   | 4.5
1   | 3.4
```

Please help!

Comment: I think you should clarify what do you mean by _Find all As where (GROUP BY bb->'d' and pick first one)_

Comment: @MladenJablanović thank you very much for your response. I've updated question description. Please review. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm afraid you are trying to go a bit too far with SQL. Your JSON field contains an array of records. I think you should extract these structures to a proper DB schema first. Or implement part of the logic in Ruby.